# An internal error occurred during: "Updating indexes".Java heap space during eclipse start up?

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I am getting below error  while starting eclipse

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating indexes".Java heap space?
```

It was running fine half an hour before.I restarted the eclipse and getting this error now? i have 8 gb ram,window 7 64 bit OS.
i have tried restarting my system but nothing helped?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-showLocation
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

**Not sure what i is the issue?**

Comment: You should try upping the heap size, just in case it actually ***is*** the problem. Set -Xmx2048m, restart Eclipse, then clean all projects. Close Eclipse and relaunch.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have m2e or other Maven plugin installed, you should check if the option at '**Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository updates index on startup**' is enabled.  Disable it and see if it resolves out of memory issue.

Comment: Solved my problem~ @nivrig I tried increasing Xmx in eclipse.ini, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse or myeclipse, you can increase memory by making changes in .ini file (myeclipse.ini)

-Xmx2048m

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m

-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore

It will solve problem connected with heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a heap space problem, try this FAQ:
[Eclipse-Wiki: FAQ How do I increase the heap size available to Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly related to the question, but this fixed the java heap issues I had:

Launch eclipse using `eclipse -vmargs -Xmx2048m`.

From the readme included with the eclipse install:

> By default, Eclipse will allocate up to 512 megabytes of Java heap
>   memory. This should be ample for all typical development tasks.
>   However, depending on the JRE that you are running, the number of
>   additional plug-ins you are using, and the number of files you will be
>   working with, you could conceivably have to increase this amount.
>   Eclipse allows you to pass arguments directly to the Java VM using the
>   -vmargs command line argument, which must follow all other Eclipse specific arguments. Thus, to increase the available heap memory, you
>   would typically use:
>
> ```
> eclipse -vmargs -Xmx<memory size>
> ```
>
> with the  value set to greater than "512M" (512 megabytes
>   -- the default).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I got this issue and adding more memory did not solve, so I rebuilt the java index by applying [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512373#c5) from eclipse bug tracker:

I Quote:

> Click in "Quick Access", Type "Rebuild Java Index" (Actually just start typing it, use the auto completion), Hit enter.